# Отметить item активным. NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Здравствуйте. У меня с сервера подгружается список категорий. Когда я запускаю фрагмент(делаю клик из меню), то айтем меню отмечается как активный и загружается определённый фрагмент. Но если повернуть экран и открыть меню, то видно что пункт текщуего фрагмента не отмечен как активный. В методе onCreate (...)  у фрагмента я проверяю на пустоту item'ы, вижу записи в логе о существовании категорий. Затем пишу следующее:

```
 navigation.getMenu().getItem(cat_id).setChecked(true).setCheckable(true)
```

Но айтем всё равно не отмечается. Дайте пожалуйста направление

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код нужно вызывать после того как NavigationDrawer проинитилась, но она не всегда срабатывает. Попробуйте:

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_profile));
```

Comment: Ну так я так и делаю, всё равно не работает.

Comment: Если в onCreate() я уже могу узнать список и кол-во своих айтемов, значит NavigationDrawer проинтилась,  верно же? Или что вы имеете ввиду? Что значит 'но она не всегда срабатывает'?

Comment: Вы использовали onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_profile));  - ? и не получается?